# I traded in expensive phones to a cell carrier that falsely advertised service in my area, now they're holding my trade-in credit hostage

Tags: contract-law, consumer-protection

In Arizona. This large cell provider claims they have full coverage in my area, but there is zero. I took no action for months because I worked long hours away from my town and didn't realize the extent of the coverage issue. The agreement for the trade-in was that the worth of your old phones will be given as a monthly credit on your bill over the course of two years. They are telling me if I cancel their service I will entirely lose out on the worth of my trade-ins, basically telling me I either bear with their cell service failure for two years or else I'll lose my large chunk of money. I don't feel comfortable having no cell service for two years, but I also don't feel comfortable with them taking nearly the full value of my old phones. The only thing they've offered is installing a mini tower at my house which isn't possible. Is there any realistic course of action?

Answer (score 4):

When you offer a thing of value (such as a phone) in exchange for something of value, you have a contract. Whether or not there is a breach of contract depends on the terms of that contract. So you would take a look at your copy of the contract and see what they promised to you, then if you are not getting what they promised, you can sue them for breach of contract. Contracts vary substantially from provider to provider. Something that I have never seen is a promise of specific network availability, but I have seen availability disclaimers. If you do find such a guarantee of network availability which clearly identifies the location(s) where you are having a problem, then you can point this out to them, and if that isn't persuasive to them, take the contract to your lawyer who will be happy to escalate the matter for you.